# What's the best algorithm for massive Email marketing

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a website with more than 35k users, who can opt-in to receive coupons, offers, discounts and some other information.

I have a huge issue, the list is too big!

Months ago, I would just make a for-each and everything was fine, but now, obviously the script just timeout.

Here a real example:

```
...
$every_email = $this->ads_model->getAllEmails();
foreach ($every_email as $duty) {
    $this->dispatcher_model->addDispatch($duty, $header, $body);
    $i++;
}
...
```

Any suggestion, service or better code improvement?

Answer (score 2):

php-script usually has limitation on execution time to kill stuck processed.
You can set it longer, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php.
Also, I would strictly suggest, like other people here, to split your big list by chunks and process each chunk by separate run of your php, using cron.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to send all email's during one script call.

A scheduling should fix your problem.
For example you can use a queue or flags inside your list.

Your sending script could be then triggered by a cronjob and send mail's in chunk's of e.g. 100 mails.